# Is the Direct Comparison Test theorem valid for strict inequalities?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

In the book *Introduction to Calculus* (Kuratowski, K.) it is mentioned that

> «... the relations ≤ and ≥ “are still true at the limit”, but the relations < and > do not have this property».

However, I think it is the only book I have read that makes such an observation. This confuses me, because usually the Direct Comparison Test theorem is stated as:

If $0 ≤ b_n ≤ a_n$ and if the series $a_1 + a_2 + ...$ is convergent, then the series $b_1 + b_2 + ...$ is also convergent. In addition, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n ≥ \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n.$$

But, depending on the source, this same theorem is stated using strict inequalities. Is that correct? And if it is not, does it have to do with what is mentioned in *Introduction to Calculus*?

Thank you very much for your time and your response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Kuratowski probably means is more general: if you have two sequences $x_n,y_n$ with $$y_n<x_n$$ then it does not imply $$\lim_n y_n < \lim_n x_n$$ but only $$\lim_n y_n \leq \lim_n x_n$$

However you are in a more special setting so you can conclude more. Namely if $b_n\leq a_n$ and at least for one index $i$ you have $a_i-b_i=C>0$ then clearly $$\sum a_n \geq \sum b_n + C$$ ergo $$\sum a_n > \sum b_n.$$

Comment: Thus, in case of strict inequality, the theorem could be stated as follows:

If $0≤b_n<a_n$ and if the series $a_1+a_2+...$ is convergent, then the series $b_1+b_2+...$ is also convergent. Furthermore, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n ≥ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n,$$

Right?

On the other hand, I have doubts about your definition of $C$. Exactly how do we conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n ≥ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n + C$? Because that statement is equivalent to saying that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n + b_i ≥ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n + a_i$, with $a_i > b_i$. But that isn't always true, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Your citation mean, that when we have $a_n \leqslant b_n$ and exist both limits, then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n \leqslant \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}b_n$, but we cannot conclude same for $a_n < b_n$, using only limit properties. We need additional info. This is meaning of words "still true". Generally, is better to keep strict inequality everywhere possible, because it give more wide visibility of situation.